# Запуск програмы из планировщика заданий Windows (task scheduler)

Tags: windows, планировщик-задач

В планировщике заданий Windows (task scheduler) у меня есть задание, которое запускает программу через определенный интервал (написана на C#). В ходе работы программы записываются файлы в папку, из которой запущена программа (они записываются библиотекой, к которой на данный момент нет доступа, поэтому не могу подать путь, используя `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`).

Если создать bat файл, в котором будет переход в директорию и запуск, то тогда файлы копируются в директорию запуска. Однако, если из планировщика запускать не bat, а сам exe, то тогда файлы сохраняются в системную папку.

Как мне настроить запуск программы, что бы программа запускалась не из системной папки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел где это устанавливается, вдруг кому поможет.

[image: Рабочая папка]